# Estimating days with block solving frequency: sanity check

Tags: blockchain, block-interval

The current block is 710908. If 212 blocks are solved per hour, then 30 days from now, we should roughly be at block 863548:

```
710908 + (30 * 24 * 212) = 863548
```

But... that's a lot bigger than 710908! Has block solving sped up? If not, that means ETH is only (710908 / 24 / 212) = 139.72 days old.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current block is 4154955.

Check that your node is fully synced, and that you're on the main network not one of the various test networks. Test networks are occasionally newly created or reset, so they will often have lower block numbers than the main network.

Answer (score 2):

[Current block number](https://etherscan.io/blocks) is `4154921`, not `710908`. The original design of 12 seconds (now more due to difficulty adjustment) was first chosen and research suggested that 12.6 seconds, but actually average is 15 seconds. So if using 15s computing, the result is:
`4154921 * 15 / 3600 / 24 = 721.34`days. you can find the [genesis block](https://etherscan.io/block/0) , and timestamp formatted is `745 days 10 hrs ago`, so it's correct completely.

Hope is helps~